# VLC player doesn't play 4K webm format files image, only audio

Tags: video, vlc, display-resolution

I use UbuntuStudio 18.04.1 LTS (64 bit) into an HP 250 G5 notebook, with Pentium N3710 (4 cores) processor, 8 GB RAM.

When I use VLC 3.0.3 multimedia player, I can not to see the image of 4K webm format files. I can only hear the audio.

It is some VLC specific problem with the webm format decoding, because when I play a 4K mp4 format file, I can see the image and hear audio, without important issues.

Is there some fix to this? Where? How?

Answer (score 2):

I use Xubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (64 bit) in ACER Aspire ES 11, with Pentium N3700 (4 cores) processor, 4 GB RAM. While using VLC 3.0.3, same problem (video jammed but audio ok) with mp4 files from my camera (old Sony DSC-W275) but not with files saved as mp4 by Kdenlive. Parole Media Player did not have this problem.

I made following changes in VLC settings, Tools/Preferences/Video:

Output: Automatic -> X11 Video Output (XCB),
Deinterlacing: Automatic -> On,
Mode: Auto -> Blend

After changes the problem disappeared.

Comment: Antti! I tried it, before, but it didn't work in my case. I can see videos (without major problems) up to 2160x1440. Anything bigger than that... Nothing! Just audio. It is the same with Parole.

Comment: Juan! I am sorry to hear that your problem with video decoding persists. Your reply seems to point to something that is common both to Parole and VLC. I didn't study the issue further as changing VLC settings helped in my case.

Comment: I can confirm that this issue is the same with Parole and Gnome MPV. I tested the same video (3840x2160 pixels resolution), with MP4 codec and Parole can show it without problems (VLC and other players can show it with problems, but...). But... Nothing happen with Webm codec. So... I guess the Webm codec needs too much power from the CPU, so... The old slower CPU can not to work so fine it.